# Problemas con el DPI

Tags: vb.net

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación y para ella uso un PC (Windows 7) y un portátil (Windows 10).

El problema es que cuando edito algo en el portátil me cambia el valor del `designer.vb`:

> `Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)` por `Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(8.0!, 16.0!)`.

También me aumenta los tamaños de `Me.ClientSize` y de `Me.MinimumSize` y el tamaño de todos los contenedores (Tabpages, listviews, ...).

He leído que se debe a la configuración del DPI pero tanto en el PC como en el Portátil están al 100%.

Lo único que cambia es la resolución que el Portátil es de 1920x1080 y en el PC es de 1280 x 1024 pero he forzado el portátil a la misma resolución y en cuanto cambio algo, cualquier movimiento de un simple botón, se desajusta todo.

UPDATE 1:

En el portátil tengo conectada otra pantalla. Tanto el portátil como la pantalla configuradas con la misma resolución y DPI. Al desconectar la pantalla y dejar solo la del portátil, el comportamiento es correcto y no me cambia ni tamaños ni posiciones.

¿Que puede ser si todo esta igual?